# Passing 'success_url' to CBV Django-Registration

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-registration

I'd like to pass a **success_url** to the class-based ActivationView in Django Registration like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930526/getting-django-registration-to-send-you-to-the-page-you-were-originally-trying) covers for function-based views and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901724/how-to-redirect-people-after-they-register-using-django-registration) covers for RegistrationView. What I have tried so far that has been unsuccessful:

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
    ActivationView.as_view({'success_url':'/activation_routing'}),
    name='registration_activate',                              
    ),
```

returns "TypeError: as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" I have also tried

and:

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
    ActivationView.as_view(success_url='/activation_routing'),
    name='registration_activate',                              
    ),
```

returns "TypeError: ActivationView() received an invalid keyword 'success_url'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class."

I feel like I'm missing something with class-based views, or is subclassing ActivationView and putting in custom logic my best bet?

Comment: I did overwrite ActivationView by providing a new success_url, but I had wrong path in urls.py. If 'auth/' is path for django_registration, then 'auth/activate/<str:activation_keys>/ should be path for our custom ActivationView

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed only pass existing attributes to `as_view()`. As such, and looking at the [source of django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration), the view doesn't have a `success_url` attribute but it obtains its value by calling `self.get_success_url(...)`.

By default this method is not implemented so you have little choice besides subclassing `ActivationView` and implementing `get_success_url` yourself.

Comment: I think the package would be better designed if the `ActivationView` class included a base implementation of `get_success_url` similar to those found on the editing CBVs, along with a `success_url = None` declaration so that keywords to `as_view` would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'll add in an example of subclassing ActivationView for future reference for others.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to subclass the view and override the `get_success_url` method.

I opened [pull request 57](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/pull-request/57/allow-changing-of-success_url-for-simple/diff) to enable setting `success_url` as a class attribute, but it has not been merged yet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, hope your pull request gets approved! Definitely looks like this would resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As others confirmed, I was able to resolve this by subclassing [ActivationView](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/views.py?at=default#cl-112) and overriding the get_success_url() and activate() methods:

```
"""
views.py
"""    

from registration.views import ActivationView  

class CustomActivation(ActivationView):                          
    def activate(self, request, *args, **kwargs):                  
        return True

    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        success_url =  # insert success URL here 
        return success_url
```

It's also important to set the correct URL in your urls.py file to override the default ActivationView that will be called by django-registration. One quirk to remember is that django-registration will set its URLs according to the filepath of auth.urls and not what you specify in your app's urls.py file:

```
"""
urls.py
"""

from yourapp.views import CustomActivation

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^user_settings/', include('auth.urls')),
    url(r'^user_settings/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
        CustomActivation.as_view(),
        name='registration_activate',
        ),
    # will still set registration URLs under user_settings!
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```